# TextFormField is not working. Here is the code and problem below

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
Scaffold(
    body:Stack(
        children:[
            Positioned(
                top:120,
                child:Container(
                    child:Column(
                        children:[
                            TextFormField(
                                validator: (value) {
                                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                        return 'Please enter some text';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                },
                            ),
                        ]
                    )
                )
            )   
        ]
    )
);
```

This message shows:

> The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: _RenderDecoration#03a2b
> relayoutBoundary=up20 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:
> needs compositing
> creator: _Decorator ← InputDecorator ← AnimatedBuilder ← Listener ← RawGestureDetector ← TextSelectionGestureDetector ← Semantics ← AnimatedBuilder ← IgnorePointer ← _RawMouseRegion ← MouseRegion ← TextField ← ⋯
>   parentData:  (can use size)
>   constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
>   size: MISSING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you make your `Positioned` a `Positioned.fill`, it will layout its children in bounded space as opposed to unbounded.  Once it has these constraints, it can pass them down to `Column` & `TextFormField` so they can size themselves within bounded space.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FieldColumnPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body:Stack(
            children:[
              Positioned.fill(
                top: 120,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'field here'
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ]
        )
    );
  }
}
```

This is a quirk of `Stack's` layout algorithm.  Here's the comments on `Stack` in the SDK:

```
/// The stack sizes itself to contain all the
/// non-positioned children, which are positioned according to [alignment]
/// (which defaults to the top-left corner in left-to-right environments and the
/// top-right corner in right-to-left environments). The positioned children are
/// then placed relative to the stack according to their top, right, bottom, and
/// left properties.
```

If I'm understanding that correctly...

- the `Stack` sizes itself to **contain** *non-Positioned children*
- but you have **zero** non-Positioned children
- so, `Stack` lays out Positioned children, in **unbounded space** (not explicitly stated in comment, but it's my guess)
- `Column` lays out non-flex factor widgets (anything not `Flexible` or `Expanded`), also in **unbounded space**
- `TextFormField` decorator tries to expand as wide as possible to fill constraints
- there are no constraints in unbounded space
- app explodes

By switching to `Positioned.fill`, Position now figures out how much space it has (its constraints) and passes those constraints down to its children which are now bounded by those constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `TextFormField` with a `Row` widget which has `mainAxisSize` set to `MainAxisSize.min`. And also set `Column`'s `mainAxisSize` to min value.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set width to the parent container of your TexFormField because TextFormField get parent size and container and all parents to the top hasn't specified width when you use TextFormField in row you can put TextFormField in Expanded widget and in stack I think you can do it too.